# SQLite 3 - Is there a way to export a database file to a tab-delimited text file?

Tags: linux, sqlite

I currently have a large 15 GB database .db file in my linux EC2 server. I know that SQLite 3 can directly export to a .csv file using this command:

```
sqlite3 -header -csv ./home/data.db "select * from datafile;" >> out.csv
```

However, I was wondering if there was an option for exporting a .db file into a tab-delimited text file instead. I looked up and down the documentation for SQLite 3 but only found references to .csv files. Would anyone know anything on how I could do this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 11):

Sure:

```
sqlite3 -header -separator " " ./home/data.db \
    "select * from datafile;" > out.txt
```

should do it.  The contents of `" "` is the tab character.  You can type if from the command line (in `bash`) by preceeding it with a `Ctrl-v`.

You can use `"\t"` if you are using a SQL script:

```
.headers on
.mode csv
.separator "\t"
select * from datafile
```

See also [the manual](https://sqlite.org/cli.html), section 5.  Also from the manual:

> 8.6.2. Export to TSV (tab separated values)

> Exporting to pure TSV, without any field quoting, can be done by entering ".mode tabs" before running a query. However, the output will not be read correctly in tabs mode by the ".import" command if it contains doublequote characters. To get TSV quoted per RFC 4180 so that it can be input in tabs mode with ".import", first enter ".mode csv", then enter '.separator "\t"' before running a query.

Comment: You can use `$'\t'` if you are using a script.

`sqlite3 -separator $'\t' ...`